# Why am I getting this weird permissions-related text whenever I run pip2/pip3 in my Linux Mint Terminal?

Tags: linux, permissions, python, sudo, cache

Note: I created this account because of this question. :)

Okay then: Let's begin.

I noticed that I receive the following "message" in my Linux Mint 18.2 Terminal whenever I go to install a new Python package using `pip2`/`pip3` with `sudo` (which is required to install new Python packages using `pip2`/`pip3`):

> The directory '/home/kyle/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>   The directory '/home/kyle/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

For example, here's a "screenshot" of sorts of my Terminal when I do such a thing (of course there are no empty lines between lines of Terminal output; that's me making this output readable here in this post); the same thing happens when I replace `pip2` with `pip3`:

> kyle@kyle-B301 ~ $ sudo pip2 install pytest pytest-cache
>
> The directory '/home/kyle/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>
> The directory '/home/kyle/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>
> Collecting pytest
>
> Downloading pytest-3.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (187kB)
>
> 100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 380kB/s
>
> Collecting pytest-cache
>
> Downloading pytest-cache-1.0.tar.gz
>
> Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pytest)
>
> Collecting py>=1.4.33 (from pytest)
>
> Downloading py-1.4.34-py2.py3-none-any.whl (84kB)
>
> 100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 689kB/s
>
> Collecting execnet>=1.1.dev1 (from pytest-cache)
>
> Downloading execnet-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40kB)
>
> 100% |████████████████████████████████| 40kB 1.3MB/s
>
> Collecting apipkg>=1.4 (from execnet>=1.1.dev1->pytest-cache)
>
> Downloading apipkg-1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>
> Installing collected packages: py, pytest, apipkg, execnet, pytest-cache
>
> Running setup.py install for pytest-cache ... done
>
> Successfully installed apipkg-1.4 execnet-1.4.1 py-1.4.34 pytest-3.2.2 pytest-cache-1.0
>
> kyle@kyle-B301 ~ $

As you can see, everything works (which is good). It's just those two lines about me, a "sudoer", not "owning" directories which are in my own "home" directory that does not make sense!

Update:
As suggested by "G-Man", I ran `ls -laR /home/kyle/.cache/pip` (I narrowed it to `/home/kyle/.cache/pip` because it is the "problem" directory), and the results can be found here (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rqRBEAXXVcJNwwojHj7fDOoyNvenvj4VYFFq0-s5gTs/edit?usp=sharing).

If someone can please explain to me the cause of these messages and a solution to resolving the "apparent" lack of "ownership" to these directories (which I can easily navigate to without `sudo` permissions), then I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, have you verified the ownership on the directory? What do you mean “directories which are not in my own "home" directory”? Are you kyle or not?

Comment: Actually, I miss-typed (thanks for inadvertently pointing it out). They "are" in my "home" directory. And yes, `kyle` is my user account. Sorry. However, how could I "verify the ownership on the directory", as you say?

Comment: Do ``ls -laR /home/kyle/.cache`` and post the results in your question .

Comment: Done (although I ran `ls -laR /home/kyle/.cache/pip` to narrow the results; if that is not enough I will do the whole `~/.cache` directory). I'll be back here to check on things tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  It certainly looks like you own everything in that directory tree; maybe somebody else will see something in there that explains it.

Comment: That's strange. Thank you for your help, though!

Comment: Don’t give up hope yet.  [SE] (of which [SU] is a part) has users all around the world (in different time zones).  It’s been less than 24 hours since you posted your question; some people still haven’t seen it.

Comment: That's a completely valid point. I can wait. It's not really a huge problem. It's just a mystery to me. Thanks though!